# Suppressing parskip in proofs

Tags: ntheorem, parskip

I would like to use parskip to avoid indent and also to have some space between paragraphs. However, I would like this feature only in the text inbetween proofs (like introduction etc). Inside the proofs I want to have zero parskip.

I am using ntheorem.sty and with the following settings for the proofs:

```
    \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
    \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
    \theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
    \theoremseparator{.} % e.g. Proof.
    \theorempreskip{\topsep}
    \theorempostskip{\topsep} %\topsep refers to the space that LATEX inserts above and below lists
    \theoremindent0cm
    \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square} % at the end of the Theorem
    \qedsymbol{$\Box$}

    \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I suppose in this case you want a non-zero `\parindent` inside proofs?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example. This doesn't even tell us how you are changing `\parskip`. Are you using the `parskip` package, which is recommended? (Insofar as this is recommended at all. Perhaps `less strongly dis-recommended` would be better.)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\normalparindent
\setlength\normalparindent{\parindent}
\usepackage{parskip,kantlipsum,ntheorem,etoolbox}
\newlength\normalparskip
\setlength\normalparskip{\parskip}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorempreskip{\normalparskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep}
\theoremindent0cm
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\qedsymbol{$\Box$}

\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\pretocmd{\proof}{\setlength\parindent{\normalparindent}\setlength\parskip{0pt}}{\typeout{Patched proof OK.}}{\typeout{Patching proof failed.}}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-2]

\begin{proof}
  \kant[3-4]
\end{proof}

\kant[5-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: Kant around proof]

## EDIT

In response to your deleted answer, which was really a comment, note first that my initial answer above was, basically a waste of time. This is my fault: I shouldn't have answered a question without code. In essence, your follow-up is an entirely different question as it is about KOMA Script.

***This is why (very nearly almost absolutely) all questions should include code for a minimal document which can be used to reproduce the problem.***

In any case, I do not really think this is entirely wise with a KOMA class. In particular, to get good results, you need to set `parskip` to `full`. Otherwise, pages will not be flush at the bottom. (I'm not sure if `full` is sufficient to ensure this, but it hopefully is and should certainly help.) To my eye, this looks silly as the skip is too large. But the other option, `half`, will result in ragged page bottoms, which looks even worse. Especially, it looks worse with a KOMA class, I think, as KOMA tries so hard to avoid this kind of thing.

Anyway, in this case, you can, if you must, use something like the following.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,ntheorem,etoolbox}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\qedsymbol{$\Box$}

\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\pretocmd{\proof}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}{\typeout{Patched proof OK.}}{\typeout{Patching proof failed.}}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-2]

\begin{proof}
  \kant[3-4]
\end{proof}

\kant[5-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: KOMA case]